# What happens if you compile an empty java file?

Tags: java

When I compiled an empty Java file it didn't produce any class file. So I want to know how compiler react when compiling an empty Java file? I thought it should generate an empty class file in this case, but it did not. So why it didn't?

Comment: Sounds like you answered your own question. If you want to know *why* it happened, that's a different question.

Comment: I asked Why too i think.

Comment: This is what happens, if (javaFileContent.indexOf("class")<-1) return null; :) im just kidding of course

Comment: There's no such thing as an empty `.class` file. A `.class` file defines a class.

Comment: What kind of question is this?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`javac` starts, sees there is no class declared in the file, and finishes. In order for a `.class` file to be created you must at least have the class declaration in the file.

Comment: So dose it mean a successful compilation without errors?

Comment: Yes, it is a successful compilation without errors in my case.  You can always read the exit status of last command by `echo $?` under Bash. Or under Windows Command Prompt, it is `echo %errorlevel%`.

Answer (score 7):

What most of the answers are saying is really that a class file is not a compiled java file but a binary representation of a class.

Compiling a java file could result in two class files if the java file contains two classes (although only one can be public) and that is why compiling something with zero classes will result in zero class files.

Answer (score 1):

If the file is totally empty and just called .java then there is nothing for the compiler to do when you attempt to generate a class file. If you do have a

```
class Foo {
}
```

segment in the .java file then an empty calss file (Foo.class) will be generated

Answer (score 1):

Well given that a Java file could be like this:

```
// Foo.java 
class Bar
{
}
```

How would it know what to call the thing?  Also should it make it a class or an interface or an enum?

Rather than make the choice for you it does nothing (I would have expected an error myself... but nothing is a sane thing to do as well).

Comment: Almost-empty .java files are used for package annotations, so doing nothing with an empty source file makes a bit more sense than treating it as an error. See http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/packages.html#7.4.1.1

Answer (score 1):

javac creates a class file for each class declaration (explicit or anonymous).
since your java file contained none, the compiler justly didn't generate any class files.

Answer (score 1):

If you would've declared the class, (e.g., `public class test{ }` ), it would compile and create `test.class` file. It would not run b'cos it doesn't have a `main` method.

Comment: It is actually possible to create (at least with OpenJDK 1.6) an empty file and compile it, but: 1. it won't generate a `.class` file and 2. it won't generate warnings.

Answer (score 0):

class Emptyclass 
{
}

//Emptyclass can be compiled sucessfully and .class file is also generated, but during execution it fails, because JVM doesnot find 'Main Method' in class 'Emptyclass'

Comment: while true, failing execution wasn't the question, was it :-)

Answer (score 0):

Java will not create class file of that java file. Because First it will look for class name. So nothing will happen

Answer (score -2):

Javac starts and checks the size of file and if its zero then it just returns without creating any .class file.