# Why blank(empty file) java do not not show any error?

Tags: java

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happens if you compile an empty java file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2467723/what-happens-if-you-compile-an-empty-java-file)

I tried to compile a blank file(.java file)hoping it will show an error.But Java compiler did not shown any error why so?

Comment: There is no error in an empty file. Why would the compiler raise one ?

Comment: @dystroy It's not weird to expect the compiler to raise an error about missing classes

Comment: @Keyser You don't ask the compiler to build a class, but to build all the classes it founds in a list of files you pass. If there is none, it simply has nothing to do. Initially, you could even have all your classes in only one java file...

Comment: If you take a look at the [java grammar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se5.0/html/syntax.html), you'll see that it starts with optional symbols. `CompilationUnit:
        [[Annotations] package QualifiedIdentifier   ;  ] {ImportDeclaration}
        {TypeDeclaration}`

Comment: @dystroy That's kind of obvious. But it's **not** weird to expect the compiler to require at least one class. A warning could very well be appropriate.

Comment: Why c compiler shows  an error then?Is C compiler is more smart?